# Need to convert values into names in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have values within a database table which has color codes like #ffffff and i hope to show in active_admin the values in simple words.

For example for #ffffff, the value in words is "white". It is simpler to do in normal rails code but in active admin with the DSL, i'm confused.

I have tried a basic configuration:

```
      row("Paper Color") { order.colorpaper }
```

Which comes out as a value of #ffffff (if i selected "white" in my frontend) from order.colorpaper model.

But in my prints.rb model as well, there is a list of it, concatenated in MY_COLORS, usually invoked using Prints::MY_COLORS in normal rails configuration.

```
      MY_COLORS = {
  white:       '#ffffff',
  green:       '#7bd148',
  bold_blue:   '#5484ed',
  blue:        '#a4bdfc',
  turquoise:   '#46d6db',
  light_green: '#7ae7bf',
  bold_green:  '#51b749',
  yellow:      '#fbd75b',
  orange:      '#ffb878',
  red:         '#ff887c',
  bold_red:    '#dc2127',
  purple:      '#dbadff',
  gray:        '#e1e1e1'
}
```

Comment: please show the code you already have or you did try.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering myself on how i did it in active admin:

```
 row "Cover Paper Color" do
       if(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#ffffff')
          "White"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#7bd148')
          "Green"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#5484ed')
          "Bold Blue"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#a4bdfc')
          "Blue"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#46d6db')
          "Turquoise"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#51b749')
          "Bold Green"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#fbd75b')
          "Yellow"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#ffb878')
          "Orange"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#ff887c')
         "Red"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#dc2127')
          "Bold Red"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#dbadff')
          "Purple"
       elsif(order.covercolorpaperpages == '#e1e1e1')
          "Gray"
       else
          "None"
       end
```